# Animate UITableViewCell with genie effect

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, core-animation

I'm stuck. I have a TableView with messages. Upon selection these will be deleted and moved to trash. I get the genie effect real easy by using it in `controller:didChangeContent [...] case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` but it animaties **behind** the other cells. But I want it **on top** of the other cells. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the animation Code:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"suck" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:103 forView:myCell cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationPosition:CGPointMake(50, 710)];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Got the Idea from [here](http://www.iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIViewAnimationState).

Comment: these are private API's, Apple might reject your app.

Answer (score 0):

You could try bringing your cell to the front by doing this:

```
[myCell.superview bringSubviewToFront:myCell]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get source code from this [link](https://github.com/Ciechan/BCGenieEffect)

In ViewController.m file do the following changes

```
- (void) genieToRect: (CGRect)rect edge: (BCRectEdge) edge
{    
NSTimeInterval duration = self.durationSlider.value;

CGRect endRect = CGRectInset(rect, 5.0, 5.0);

[self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)     {
    button.enabled = NO;
}];

if (self.viewIsIn) {
    [self.draggedView genieOutTransitionWithDuration:duration startRect:endRect startEdge:edge completion:^{
        self.draggedView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            button.enabled = YES;
        }];
    }];
} else {
    self.draggedView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.draggedView genieInTransitionWithDuration:duration destinationRect:endRect destinationEdge:edge completion:
     ^{
         [self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
             button.enabled = YES;
         }];}];
}

self.viewIsIn = ! self.viewIsIn;
}
```

Hope it helps.. Happy Coding !!!